# Angular material - apply different syles

Tags: angular, angular-material, styles

How to apply different styles to several angular material components in a same page:
a select/option with blue background and another one with red background ?

Example available at https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-different-styles
But it does not work !

Answer (score 2):

Since `mat-select-panel` will get attached to the overlay layer, you can't give classes to the parent element `mat-form-field`.

Instead of that you can attach the class to `mat-option`.

**app.component.scss**

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Blue backgroud">
    <mat-option class="blue" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Red backgroud">
    <mat-option class="red" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Style for the mat-option inorder to set the option background color to any color of your choice.

```
<mat-option style="background-color: red;" *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
```

In case you want to change the select background color to any color you can use

```
<mat-select placeholder="Red backgroud" style="background-color: red;">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can change `mat-option` background color as below.

```
/deep/ .mat-option{
   background-color: red;
}
```

You can change `mat-select` background color as below.

```
/deep/ .mat-select{
   background-color: red;
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-different-styles-zxcf7t?file=src/app/app.component.scss)**